# Looping URLs for scraping on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My script currently looks at a list of 5 URLs, once it reaches the end of the list it stops scraping. I want it to loop back to the first URL after it completes the last URL. How would I achieve that?

The reason I want it to loop is to monitor for any changes in the product such as the price etc.

I tried looking at a few method I found online but couldn't figure it out as I am new to this. Hope you can help!

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import random

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':ua.chrome}

# Proxies
proxy_list = []

for line in open('proxies.txt', 'r'):
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    proxy_list.append(line)

def get_proxy():
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    proxies = {
        "http": f'{str(proxy)}',
        "https": f'{str(proxy)}'
    }
    return proxies

# Opening URL file 
with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
    for url in file.readlines():
        proxies = get_proxy()
        result = requests.get(url.strip() ,headers=header,timeout=4,proxies=proxies)
        #src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the urls in a list and do a while loop over it, the basic logic will be

```
with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
    url_list = file.readlines()
pos = 0
while True:
    if pos >= len(url_list):
        pos = 0
    url = url_list[pos]
    pos += 1
    *** rest of your logic ***
```

Comment: Just tried this and got this error when it got to the last item - 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\Python Course\ebgames\bsoup.py", line 48, in <module>
    url = url_list[pos]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `while True:` loop outside and above your main with statement & for loop (and add one level of indent to every line inside). This way the program will keep running until terminated by user.